# Facebook Page Messenger not working with Webhook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-messenger, botkit

I followed the steps to setup the Facebook Messenger platform. I have successfully setup the [webhook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks), I receive messages on my webhook.
For webhooks to work, I obviously had to subscribe my page, see the screenshot.
[image]

Now the strange problem is, if I keep my page subscribed to a webhook, my facebook page messenger doesn't show any thing.
As soon as I unsubscribe my page for webhook, page messenger nicely loads.
[image]

What can I do ?

Comment: Report it as a bug …?

Comment: That's weird. It should work. I'd recommend opening a bug report on Facebook for this, and see if they can help you figure it out, or fix it if it is indeed a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked mine and it is not working, which it was yesterday, so I'm confident this is a bug.

I'd suggest opening a bug report, and in the meantime, you can download the pages for messenger app Facebook makes to access the messages while waiting for a fix.

Comment: I have opened up a bug. 
I am not aware of pages for messenger app. Please elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: Could you link the bug report please

Comment: It's in my support inbox, I cannot find any public link. I am sorry.